# Issue Migrating from Gnosis Multisig to Safe Wallet

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

When trying to migrate from Gnosis Multisig to the new Safe Wallet, I receive the following msg: "Address given is not a valid Safe Account address" yet I have the proper address. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page. We try to keep this Stack Exchange support channel to issues related to integrating [Safe{Core}](https://docs.safe.global/smart-account-overview) (our open-source smart wallet infrastructure).

Hope it helps! Louis